# Highcharts and json format

Tags: highcharts, getjson, json

I have this code for a query in a file called `querytojson.php`:

```
if(!$query = @pg_query("SELECT AVG(\"UploadSpeed\") AS \"UploadSpeed\",
                               AVG(\"DownloadSpeed\") AS \"DownloadSpeed\",
                               AVG(\"Latency\") AS \"Latency\",
                               AVG(\"Jitter\") AS \"Jitter\",
                               AVG(\"PacketLoss\") AS \"PacketLoss\" FROM \"ZipPerformance\" "))
die("<br>Errore nella query: " . pg_last_error($query));

while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($query)){
  // aggiungo all'array
  $risultati[] = $row;  
}
// stampo a video i risultati formattati secondo la sintassi di JSON 
echo json_encode($risultati);
```

the json data is in this format:

```
[{"UploadSpeed":"0.342153197182936","DownloadSpeed":"4.35602301750153","Latency":"110.290067528565","Jitter":"0.0333323723888251","PacketLoss":"0.164373075044556"}]
```

Now I'd want to create a graph with Highcharts library like this, the file is called `index1.html`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {

            chart: {

                renderTo: 'container',

                defaultSeriesType: 'column'

            },

            title: {

                text: 'HOBBIT'

            },
            tooltip: {

            },
            labels: {
                html: 'index.html'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {

                title: {

                    text: 'Velocità di connessione'

                }

            },

            series: []

        };
})
```

I'd want to pass json data directly to `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I've done somthing similar to this. The way i did it was I created the chart in a sperate js file and just called the chart as a function passing in the JSON object as a variable.  This is an example of one of my scripts in use on my site. In your case the labels and values are the same variable so the loop iteration is different, but the idea is still the same.

```
var chart;
function pieChart(id, values, labels, animate){
    if (animate === undefined ){
        animate = true;
    }
    var arrays = new Array();
    for (i=0;i<values.length;i++)   {
        arrays[i] = [labels[i], values[i]];
    }

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: id,
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Event Occurrence',
        style: {
            color: '#000000'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
                }
            }
        },
        series: {
            animation: animate
            }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Probability',
        data: arrays
    }]
});
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Can you do an example for passing JSON as a object.

Comment: Sure, is your querytojson.php an AJAX call or is it ran on pageload?